# Is it possible to use XSLT extensions (sitecore extensions) in XSLT editor in VisualStudio?

Tags: visual-studio, xslt

I'd like to use vs2008 to edit sitecore's xslt it is a regular xslt with normal .net extensions.

Is it possible to add the extension objects to the xslt processor context in visual studio 2008 or visual studio 2010?

It can be done easily in code using AddExtensionObject. But I'm not sure how to accomplish the same thing in visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I've found is creating a console application that runs the XSLT with all the extensions object added. Then one can debug that application and step in to the xslt transformation that uses the VisualStudio xslt debugging abilities.

For more details check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255603(VS.80).aspx